# How much can we trust our dreams?

Tags: hadith, dream

Probably, it is considered as a common matter for everyone to encounter/see many dreams during his/her daily or nightly sleeping. Occasionally, it is said that some of dreams could have actual Ta'bir/Tafsir (interpretation), and actually they will be happened in the future.

So, I was wondering if we can trust our dreams. If so, how much can we trust them as actual happenings which are going to be happened in the future? Is there any related hadith (tradition)?

Comment: Did you read the story of Prophet Yusuf(pbuh) Surah 12 complete. DO that today. Gud story... you'll be answered I hope.

Comment: Oh, you mentioned a nice instance regarding that. I've read that to some extent. I'll do it again detailed. that would be beneficial for me. Well done mate.

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/23917/11938) could help you

Comment: i think that , probably, not all dreams tell about future.

Comment: Oh, yeah, you are right. Actually AFAIK solely a limited category of them can be deemed as the right one. Thank you for mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him and his household) said:

> الرؤيا ثلاثة: رؤيا بشرى من الله، ورؤيا تحزين من الشيطان، ورؤيا يحدث
>   بها الانسان نفسه، فيراها في النوم
>
> (Briefly and approximate translation): There are three types of
>   dreams, the dreams  :
>
> 1: which are Beshaarat (good news) from Allah
>
> 2: which are … from Satan
>
> 3: which are reflex of our spiritual matters (based on daily
>   behaviors and thoughts…)

Although there is a kind of dream which supposed as a true or Saadegheh dreams, but apparently majority of dreams look to be false. (Of course there are some conditions for True Dreams…)

---

**Sources And More Info. :**

[www.islamquest.net (1)](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa19797)

[www.islamquest.net (2)](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa5475)

[www.islamquest.net (3)](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa7850)

[www.pasokhgoo.ir](http://www.pasokhgoo.ir/node/28078)