# Dreams in sufism (Sufi View)

Tags: sufism, dream, books

As I know, dreams —specially dervish dreams— are very important in some sufi orders.  Do anyone know some studies, books or articles related with this regard.  Years ago I knew about a buddhist book about dreams and dreaming which particular topic is the "yoga of dreaming". I am particularly interested in knowing if there is in the sufi path some knowledge about how to prepare oneself to the state of "openness" previous to a dervish dream to apear and if there is some guide or advise once I am aware that I am "inside" a dervish dream.

Comment: Book on dervish dreams? - Yes yes yes, there is this book available in the market, called "Qur'an", explains everything well enough, good book, yeah! And about dream interpretation, plz go through this if time permits, [Interpretation of Dreams](http://www.islamicity.com/mosque/sunnah/bukhari/087.sbt.html) Maybe you'll get your answer.

Comment: And this might also help you [Dreams and dream interpretation](http://islamqa.info/en/6537)

Comment: Dear servantoWiser:  I think I was very clumsy because I make you believe that what I want is a book.  Sorry, no.  In stead what I meant is if there is some knowledge available in regard of dreaming in the context of sufism.  Of course! In some level of interpretation this knowledge is inside the Qur'an the thing is that as I told I am clumsy and I will be very thankful if you can guide me inside that particular topic.

Comment: I will try to understand the knowledge that you point out in your links but I have a an additional question.  Why do you refer to me to this particular links if all is expressed well enough in the Qur'an.  Even more, can you please tell me —in order to me to go out of my ignorance— why if all is well enough expressed in the Qur'an it is needed a page like this (islam.stackexchange.com)?  In His love, thank you very much.

Comment: Then I would plz request you to, do one thing, don't change my edit.

Comment: @servantofWiser Your edit did nothing to improve the question; all it did was open an obviously Sufi question to alternate points of view which the questioner wasn't asking for.

Comment: @servantofWiser As phrased, it doesn't appear to be a Truth question at all (I don't know enough about Sufism to be sure), but your edit effectively *turned it into one*.  It's already clearly asking for a Sufi perspective, based on (a) Sufism being explicitly mentioned in the title, (b) the tags explicitly including [tag:sufism], (c) the body explicitly asking " if there is in the sufi path some knowledge".

Comment: @servantofWiser If you have questions about how (or even whether) Sufism questions should be handled on I.SE, take it to meta; the fact that Sufis self-associate as "Muslim" is fairly obvious (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufism) which makes it de facto on-topic here (from the help centre: "[For the purposes of this site, "Islam" includes all groups that identify themselves as Muslim](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)")

Answer (score 2):

> if there is some guide or advise once I am aware that I am "inside" a dervish dream.

This article pretty much defines most of [Dreams and dream interpretation](http://islamqa.info/en/6537)

> how to prepare oneself to the state of "openness" previous to a dervish dream to appear

May be not dervish, but, preparing oneself for a truthful dream, as suggested in the article, **be truthful in your actions during the day**, then there is a possibility of getting truthful dreams. Moreover, as I discussed above, it is very very difficult to even judge our actions when we're awake whether they're right or wrong, then it similarly difficult to judge if a dream is truthful/divine or not. Example, if you get a dream "Go & kill an innocent person", you can manage to decide it's a stupid dream, but what if you get a complex dream, whereby it becomes difficult for you to decide  whether to follow it or not. So, the Islamic way of trying to achieve truthful dreams would be **get closer to Allah as much as you can**. Remember Allah much. But conditional you're following the Prophet (pbuh) perfectly. And as always, be truthful in your actions.

Piece of advice, don't solely rely on your dreams.

May the creator guide us all.

<sub>**Note:** This is not a Sufi perspective, but thought I could someway help you to explore the truth. If you wish to downvote, plz go ahead, I don't mind.</sub>

Comment: On the whole, I myself consider it as a nice and rational response. Particularly by mentioning "be truthful in your actions during the day.." and   "...truthful dreams would be get closer to Allah as much as you can..." /

Comment: (Although we are aware that occasionally our dreams are honest and true (in some specific conditions  ...)
/ as a related issue you can refer to: http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa5475

Answer (score 0):

There is a website which lists word-for-word vocubalary occurring in dreams and their possible meanings, according to a compilation attributed to an 8th century Mystic - Ibn Sirin.

I believe, different translations and rewrites of it are available on the web and on Amazon.

I use this website,
http://www.myislamicdream.com/
[Please read the first page thoroughly; it states that not everything on the site is attributed to Ibn Sirin, and does not always distinguish which explanation is from Ibn Sirin and which is not].

Also, please read the biography of Ibn Sirin and his works. There are some theories that his compilations may be inauthentic or added to by later authors.

Personally, I've found many interpretations on this site to be true (as per my own dreams); they are very symbolic and almost never literal.